# My defined function reads error value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, multiple-columns

I have the following dataframe and I need to compare the columns as follows:

- a1 vs a2
- b1 vs b2
- c1 vs c2 etc.

```
ID  Name  a1  a2  b1  b2  c1  c2  d1  d2  e1  e2  f1  f2
1   xyz   1       1   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   1   1
2   yxz   1   1   1       1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1
3   zyx   1   2   1   1   1       1   1   1   1   1   1
```

if there are differences it should be highlighted in a new column as follows:

```
ID  Name  a1  a2  b1  b2  c1  c2  d1  d2  e1  e2  f1  f2  Comment
1   xyz   1       1   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   1   1  'e different'
2   yxz   1   1   1       1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1  'd different'
3   zyx   1   2   1   1   1       1   1   1   1   1   1  'a different'
```

This is the code I'm using but I always get the following errors:

- ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
def Com_function(row):
   if df_merged['a1'] != df_merged['a2']:
       com = 'a different'
   elif df_merged['b1'] != df_merged['b2']:
       com = 'b different'
   elif df_merged['c1'] != df_merged['c2']:
       com = 'c different'
   elif df_merged['d1'] != df_merged['d2']:
       com = 'd different'
   elif df_merged['e1'] != df_merged['e2']:
       com = 'e different'
   elif df_merged['f1'] != df_merged['f2']:
       com = 'f different'
   else:
       com = ''
   return com
```

```
df_merged['Error'] = df_merged.apply(Com_function, axis=1)
```

I would appreciate the support, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by

1. Creating df for each of the column pairs (a1/a2, b1/b2 etc.)
2. Create a column with the intended error msg:

```
df_a['Error_a'] = np.where(df['a1']==df['a2'],'','a different;')
```

3. Concatenate the strings in a new column

```
df['error'] = df_a['Error_a'] + df_b['Error_b'] ...
```

Not the cleanest version but did the trick